# Convert all the values of the text to int while reading in python

Tags: python, numpy, casting

When I'm trying to convert values to int I'm getting this error in python.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,72367,72565,73005,73087,73113,73129,73313,73661,74049,74222,74350,74403,74501\n'
```

instead of this i want something like

```
0,72367,72565,73005,73087,73113,73129,73313,73661,74049,74222,74350,74403,74501
```

stored in numpy array of int

My code is

```
f = open('points.txt')
# reading the lines of the file
line = f.readline()
while line:
    points = np.array([], dtype=int)
    #print("voxel", voxel_label, " : ", line)
    points = np.append(points, line)
    line = f.readline()
    voxel_label += 1
```

When I convert points to int it gives me error. I want to read lines from text file and put that into numpy array points as int values.

```
points    array(['0,1883,1965,2176,2236,2273,2502,2528,2542,2963,2979,3288,3519\n'],
          dtype='<U62')
```

I want to convert this 'points' numpy array to int type. I'm not able to understand why there is \n at the end.

How can i convert 'points' numpy to int.

Comment: Please post the code that produced that error.

Comment: That code is unreadable in a comment. Please edit your question to add your attempted code.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put it in there? It is really hard to read in a comment.

Comment: The python function `int` accepts the string for one number, not a bunch of numbers.  Read its docs

Comment: Nothing in your code example will produce the error you are asking about.  Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve]. and [ask] as well as the other links found on that page

Comment: You may want to do something like `[int(num) for num in line.split(',')]` which splits up all the numbers and makes them an int. `line` is a line of the file which can be retreated by iterating over it

Comment: I tried this [int(num) for num in line.split(',')]

Comment: If all the lines have the same number of numbers (columns) you could load it as a `csv`, with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`.  You'd get a 2d array, one row per line of the file.

Comment: Number of numbers are not same in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is made up purely of numbers separated by commas, you'll need something like this:

```
numbers = []
with open('points.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers.extend([int(num)
                       for num in line.split(',')])

# ... do whatever with the numbers list
```

Comment: When I try this it gives  '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split' this error

Comment: Whoops just spotted an error! `f` Needs to be `line`. I'll edit